# for loop performance iteration

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, arraylist

The question is, "We might expect method3 to run faster than method2, why is that?" but I have no idea. It seems like both methods do the same amount of operations. Could someone please enlighten me?

```
ArrayList<Person> method2(Person x, ArrayList<Person> people){
    ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Person y : people) if (x.knows(y)) friends.add(y);
    return friends;  
}


ArrayList<Person> method3(Person x, ArrayList<Person> people){  
    ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>();  
    for (int=0; i<people.size(); i++){ 
        Person y = people.get(i);
        if (x.knows(y)) friends.add(y);
    }
    return friends;
}
```

Comment: In the real world, 99.99% of the time, the only meaningful difference between these two methods is readability. The performance difference between the 2 depends on the size of the list, and how ArrayList implements get and getItorator methods and will almost never matter; Any design choice based on class implementation will always be inherently wrong (except where you need to squeeze every iota of performance out, in which case you will most likely be coding on a lower level)

Answer (score 5):

It is not so.  Both methods will run at an almost identical speed.

To the extent that they will not run at exactly the same speed, two things hold:

1. It will not make a bit of a difference in any practical scenario.
2. You cannot really tell whether it will be `method2` or `method3` that will run faster.

Answer (score 4):

> "We might expect method3 to run faster than method2, why is that?"

It may but the difference should be minimal and even not considered as an information to choose the one or the other.

These two methods perform exactly the same thing with a variance : a enhanced `for` the `method2()` and a classic `for` that access to the `List` with `get(int index)` for the `method3()`.

The compiled code of `method2()` will result to the use of an iterator that at runtime may be a little more long to execute but it should really not have a significant difference.

---

For example : `hasNext()` Iterator for an `ArrayList` performs some checks and some very minor computations :

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

A`for` that uses the `get(int index)` method has less computation :

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}
```

Comment: I think the question is asking the student to recognize that `method2()` allocates an iterator, but with modern JIT optimization and the like, doing so simply doesn't slow things down in any significant way.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo You are right about the pedagogical question. Now the compiled code with iterator performs more computations. I updated to show it. These are extremely minors but these are more than `get()` method. Personally, I could not affirm that the JVM has zero processing for them after optimizations.

Comment: @davidxxx you are right, but in this case it will apply only if will use people.size() only single time and assign the value to a variable (you dont need to call size() for every item).

Comment: @Vasile Bors for size() you are right.  I referred to `ArrayList.get()` used in `method3()`  VS `ArrayList$Iterator` performance used in `method2()`